# Do I have to buy Harley Quinn’s revenge on Batman Arkham City Xbox 360?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

So, I beat the story mode and go to play Harley Quinn’s revenge but I can’t find it. Then I looked online and it said I have to buy it. Do I really? I just want answers from actual people

Comment: I don't see any version of Arkham City that includes that DLC.

Comment: @Raj the GOTY edition does, and is on Steam. No idea about the XBox store.

Comment: Does your copy of Arkham City claim that Harley Quinn's Revenge is included? If yes, does it say it's included as a download code and did you buy your copy second-hand?

Comment: Yeah, it says that I have it but there is no download code. Yes, I bought my copy second-hand.

Comment: It's possible the game came with a download code, but since it's second hand, one of the previous owners used it and disposed of the code (which would've become invalid afterwards anyway). Including a DLC as download code used to be a popular way to limit the second-hand market. I'm not sure about nowadays, but it was still done when Arkham City came out.

Answer (score 2):

Harley Quinn's Revenge is DLC. It's included if you have the [Game of the Year Edition](https://www.gamestop.com/video-games/xbox-360/games/products/batman-arkham-city-game-of-the-year-edition/10101488.html) ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007SRM5MO) to product on a different site). Otherwise, you'll have to purchase the DLC separately:

https://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Harley-Quinns-Revenge/9cd75fd4-9d4a-4e03-b0b1-f13db4f91e2e

Comment: Just so you know, the GameStop link says "Access Denied".

Comment: @Nolonar Maybe a regional issue? I'm not able to find a link to the GotY edition on MS's website, but I can include one for Amazon.

Comment: Ok, thank you guys